# OS X Music folder

Tags: itunes

What was Apple's intent behind creating the `~/Music/` folder if it isn't synchronised with Apple's very own music app? Is it a design flaw or does it serve a different specific purpose?

Comment: What do you mean? All your iTunes music is at `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music`

Comment: Apologies for not being specific enough, I updated my question

Comment: GarageBand puts its files into Music as well, as do a lot of audio-centric third party applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Mac as a Digital Hub

The existence of the ~/Music folder is not a design flaw. The folder is intended for keeping all your music in one location.

Apple's execution of its music strategy is plagued by baggage from earlier decisions and implementations. Maybe Apple's Music application will eventually better integrate with the ~/Music folder. Maybe iTunes will see the rewrite it clearly deserves.

As to why the Music folder exists at all, that is related to the premise of the Mac becoming a [digital hub](http://www.cultofmac.com/27810/the-dawn-of-apples-dominance-digital-hub-strategy-revisited/) for all your content.

### Organising Your Content

When Apple released Mac OS X, they designated a series of standard folders for their customers to use. These include ~/Documents, ~/Pictures, and ~/Public. Each folder had an intended purpose.

[image: Steve Jobs's digital hub WWDC presentation]

Over time those meaning have subtly changed or been diluted. Most however, remain largely faithful to the original design. Apple's iTunes application stores music in the ~/Music folder. Apple's iPhotos and Photos applications store photos in the ~/Photos folder.

### Beyond Apple

Apple does not claim exclusive use of the folders. Thus Apple's applications and most third party applications create sub-folders within these designated folders for their specific content or material.

There are Application Programmer Interfaces (API) that help third party applications locate and use these special folders. Judging by Apple's past actions, these folders are here to stay and only likely to gain greater importance.